# Executing more than one spec per time generates a weird behaviour in Json file

Tags: json, asynchronous, protractor

I have configured my conf file with the following  "specs: ['*-Spec.js']," as far as I know, this should load all the Spec files in my folder, right?

When I execute the command "protractor conf.js" it starts to execute my scripts without any problems but, the file im reading informations from starts to present random data, the flow I have is:

Script 1 
Generate a Json file to serve as data base for the second scenario

Script 2
Reads the data created, and work with this

The weird behaviour I mentioned is that the scripts creates one file but seems to read from another one.
File created: 
11111111A, 22222222B, 33333333C, 44444444D

Data used after the part that reads the recently created file: 
123123123A, 34534322b and so on...

And should be the same data... but! when I manualy replace * to the name of the Spec.. it works properly.. "specs: ['1 Create the Data-Spec.js'],"

Any idea why this is happening? bellow is the part of the code that created the data and reads from the file

```
Describe ("Creating a new data", function() {
var AmountofDniToCreate = [1,2,3,4,5];
it ("Create the preRequisite file", function() 
{
    var DNIarray = [];
    var EmailArray = [];
    //Create all the DNIs for Json file, those will be used to create new data
    AmountofDniToCreate.forEach(function (counterforEach){
        var dniNumberFile = getRandomNum(12345678, 99999874);
        DNIarray.push(dniNumberFile + getDniLetter(dniNumberFile));            
        EmailArray.push("email@gmail.com");
    });

    //Create outputFile with all the Itinerari DNIs
    var fs = require('fs');
    var objText = {"itinerari":DNIarray,"email": EmailArray};
    var JsonFile = JSON.stringify(objText)
    var outputFilename = "Created_Itinerari_Output.json";
    fs.writeFile(outputFilename, JsonFile, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("JSON saved to " + outputFilename);
        }

    });

it ("Login and access to the Create Itinerari screen", function() 
{
    //Execute the login
});


it ("Create the data in the system", function() 
{
//In this part, it reads a "different" file than the one that is actually created above (Should be the same!)
var jsonDNI = require('C:Mypath.../Created_Itinerari_Output.json');
};
//End
});
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what is the script. Is the script included? Are you talking about the `it` block as the script? "fs.writeFile" is async and you need to wait till it is done. Please clarify what is the script and where the file is created and where you are reading the file.

Comment: Hello @cnishina, the file was being created after the "read" action was being performed, I changed the code structure and now it is working properly, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change writing file to sync, otherwise when the second it beginning, the writing file triggered in first it may be not finished, because `fs.writeFile` is Async.

```
var content = JSON.stringify(objText)
var outputFilename = "Created_Itinerari_Output.json";
fs.writeFileSync(outputFilename, content);
```

Even, Jasmine says next it will be started when the previous it complete. 
This means next it will wait all code lines in previous it block be executed.

But not mean next it will wait the Async operations of code line complete. Except the Async operation is wrapped as promise, like protractor API: `click()`, `getText()` and so on.

Jamsine will wait all promises belongs to the previous it block to complete, then start the next it block.

Comment: Hi @yong,I changed it a little bit and instead of using 2 or 3 "It" in the same describe I'm using only one per describe and now (Creating and reading the file in the same "it" and only then using the data) and it is working properly!

vars -> Describe(creating values and file) -> it (doings what it needs)

Thank you for your explanation and help I will read more about how it works.